# What size of head is right for this monopod?

Tags: tripod-heads, monopod, ball-head

I want to get a replacement head (possible a tilt head) for this monopod.

It seems like on most online stores, the size of head is exclusively quoted in inch. Since I live outside US and I am also new to the world of photography, I am not entirely sure if I will get it right. I hope you may be able to tell me if I interpreted the size correctly.

So here is my question:

The screw in the photo is about 1 cm wide in diameter. I suppose I can fit 3/8" tilt head to it? My camera is a Fujifilm xt-20.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tripod threads are measured in diameter-threads/inch. The two most common sizes are 3/8”-16 and 1/4”-20.

Many tripods and tripod heads sport 3/8” while many cameras use 1/4”. If looking to attach your camera directly to the tripod, you’ll most likely need a 3/8” to 1/4” adapter.

These are super common in the US and can be found just about anywhere that carries hardware. Outside of the US, I’m not so sure about the hardware store but just about any decent photo equipment store should have them.

Comment: re: 1/4-20 and 3/8-16 outside of the US, they are actually ISO standard sizes for photographic purposes. So they are universal in basically all countries. Hardware stores won't have 1/4-20 or 3/8-16 necessarily, but any photo store that has accessories will have them. See also: [Is the screw for attaching tripod heads to tripods standardized?](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/104950)